# Adding one image to another with PIL on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library

I am using a raspberry Pi with a camera module. I wrote a script which made the camera module take a picture.

Now, after I took the picture I need a Python script which puts the recently taken picture and another picture (something like a watermark or logo) together. I tried to use this: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html
, but I don't know which commands or syntax I must use.

EDIT:
My Python script... It takes a picture with the time.

```
from datetime import datetime
zeit = datetime.now()
zeit = "%s-%s-%s-%s:%s:%s" % (zeit.year,zeit.day,zeit.month,zeit.hour,zeit.minute,zeit.second)
Bildformat = ".png"

Bildname = "Bild-" + zeit + Bildformat

from subprocess import call

#call (["raspistill -o " + Bildname + " -t 1 -n"], shell=True)
call (["raspistill -o /home/pi/cam_project/Bilder/" + Bildname + " -t 1 -n"], shell=True)
```

EDIT 2:
Thanks for your Answers. This is my whole Code. I want to add something like in the Tutorial (look at the link above). The main Idea is that the camera shoots a picture and the PIL library (see link) grabs the picture and add this recently taken picture to another picture (which I made before and this is in the same directory (Like a watermark or logo))

Something like:

```
from __future__ import print_function   
from PIL import Image

img_taken = Image.open("/home/pi/cam_project/Bilder/" + Bildname + "")

# This is the picture with the date as name 
    
img_watermark/logo = Image.open("home/pi/cam_project/Bilder/watermark.png
    
    # This is the logo


# Then I want something like: paste img_watermark/logo  in img_taken
```

If you click the link I posted above and scroll down to "Rolling an Image" After the code they say:

> For more advanced tricks, the paste method can also take a
> transparency mask as an optional argument. In this mask, the value 255
> indicates that the pasted image is opaque in that position (that is,
> the pasted image should be used as is). The value 0 means that the
> pasted image is completely transparent. Values in-between indicate
> different levels of transparency.

---

As output I want the processed picture (with the logo/watermark)

Comment: Sounds interesting. To get a good answer, please provide the following: 1) More detail about your inputs 2) More detail about what you want as output 3) The code you have tried (only the part related to this question)

Comment: Thanks for the update of your code. However it only shows how you get the main image. Please explain how you want to combine the images / what output you want.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll make an example as soon as I have time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will work for you. It can handle transparency in the watermark image you use and also make the watermark image brighter so it's not as visible.

```
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageEnhance

# images
base_path = 'base.jpg'
watermark_path = 'watermark.png'
base = PIL.Image.open(base_path)
watermark = PIL.Image.open(watermark_path)

# optional lightness of watermark from 0.0 to 1.0
brightness = 0.5
watermark = PIL.ImageEnhance.Brightness(watermark).enhance(brightness)

# apply the watermark
some_xy_offset = (10, 20)
# the mask uses the transparency of the watermark (if it exists)
base.paste(watermark, some_xy_offset, mask=watermark)
base.save('final.png')
base.show()
```

[image: public domain cat image]

(public domain cat image)

Comment: Thanke you ! I solved the problem yesterday in a similar way ;) But THX for your help ! :)